# De vs du, de la or de l'

Tags: prépositions, de

What is the logic to French using either just "de" or otherwise "du, de la or de l'" in front of a word? I understand the differences between "du", "de la" and "de l'", but not how it is decided to use one of those in stead of just "de".

As examples, I do not understand what the choice was based on in the following phrases:

> une compression de personnel
>
> les richesses du sous-sol
>
> l'armée de l'air
>
> l'armée de terre
>
> l'avocat de la défense
>
> l'âge de la retraite

Comment: This question was asked literally one week ago and was marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you did actually a small search on Google, you would find some good results and explanation !

I can say briefly, `de` alone with no definite article is used usually when we speak about a very GENERAL concept, just like:

- Un homme de principe/science/guerre

but when we know definitely what we are talking about, the definites articles should be added, just like:

- Le bruit de la ville

here we don't intend to say or generalize the concept of noise `bruit` to all cities.However, only a specific city that we mention.

Comment: Thanks. But the what explains the difference between: l'armée de l'air

l'armée de terre

Comment: hmm actually I can say because that the **air** is very specific and well-known and we have no air but the one in common between us all mankind + it is just one known army weapon for the air unit (I mean there is no diversity in it) so we use it with definite article.However, **terre** is not common in this sense, every land has its own territory + the army of a land usually has a set of diversity in its units unlike the air unit ! so the concept here is generalized to cover all of them.

Comment: you can check such video ... it explains the case very well 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koCNVpTRrys
+
please mark the question as "ANSWERED" if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

As for most languages, the french language practice obeys some rules. One of these rules is called *"règle de l'article contracté"*. It states that when  *"une préposition"* is followed by *"un article défini"*, the result should be "un article contracté" (contracted article).

In the case of:

> une compression **du** personnel

*"du"* is here the contracted article of *"de le"* which respectively are *"préposition + article défini"*. Consequently, it is incorrect to say:

> **une compression de le personnel**

The use of *"de"* / *"du"* depends on whether *"personnel"* is definite or not. In our case, it isn't so one must use *"du"*.

If *"personnel"* is definite, *"de"* should be used as in:

> une compression **de** personnel de la comptabilité.

Note that *"de la"* of *"de la comptabilité"* is not concerned by the rule in question since it is *"du genre féminin"* (feminine gender).